# MySQL multiple sub-queries optimization

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables
Table1 has id cell
Table2 has id cell
Table3 has id1 cell -> corresponds to Table1.id
Table3 has id2 cell -> corresponds to Table2.id

I need a result that count how many times the pair of id1 and id2 appeared in Table3, also for a result that did not appear.

So cant use simple 
Select * from table3 group by id1, id2.

I used

```
SELECT *
FROM table1, table2, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM table3
    GROUP BY id1, id2)
GROUP BY table1.id, table2.id
```

but it is slow as molasses and it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next query:

**1)** First, we cross join table1 and table2 for get all combination tuples.

**2)** Second, we left join to table3.

**3)** We count the number of rows obtained for each tuple, counting not null values on **table3->id1** (This assume that tuples of types `<null, id>` or `<id, null>` don't exists on table3)

```
SELECT
   t1.id, t2.id, COUNT(t3.id1) AS count
FROM
   table1 AS t1
CROSS JOIN
   table2 AS t2
LEFT JOIN
   table3 AS t3 ON t3.id1 = t1.id AND t3.id2 = t2.id
GROUP BY
   t1.id, t2.id
```

Comment: Showing rows 0 - 24 (34188 total, Query took 13.3809 seconds.)
So not really a fast query, though faster than mine :D

Comment: I think you need to add an index by **(id1, id2)** on table3. How much rows table3, table2 and table1 have?

Comment: I added index, and it seems much faster.
t1 - 20rows
t2 - 3000rows
t3 - 20k rows
Will test more

Answer (score 1):

I'd cross-join table1 and table2, and then left join this on table3, and count an expression to check if combination exists:

```
SELECT     t1.id,
           t2.id,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN t3.id1 IS NOT NULL AND t3.id2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END)
FROM       t1
CROSS JOIN t2
LEFT JOIN  t3 ON t1.id = t3.id1 AND t2.id = t3.id2
GROUP BY   t1.id, t2.id
```

Comment: This is missing 
GROUP BY
   t1.id, t2.id
but then its slow as anything i tried (14s), see @d-smania answer